# Javascript List of Objects in IE<9 fail to inherit from Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

I understand `Object.prototype` shouldn't be altered, but out of curiosity, what are all of the objects that fail to inherit from `Object.prototype` in IE<9?

So far all of the following fail to inherit from `Object.prototype`.

- alert
- document.createElement
- setTimeout
- setInterval
- document.createElement('i') - All other DOM elements
- document.createElement('i').appendChild - All DOM element methods included

I've created a jsbin test here.  All browsers should get success except well...IE.

http://jsbin.com/inuhux/7 - http://jsbin.com/inuhux/7/edit

**What other objects in IE<9 fail to inherit from `Object.prototype`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not assume that host objects inherit **anything** from built-in objects in any browser or user agent. There is no specification that says they must.

The W3C DOM specifications are all language neutral, they do not assume any specific language features. When they use the term ["inherit"](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1CED5498) in regard to DOM interfaces, it means "this interface has all the features of some other interface", not that any kind of inheritance must be implemented.

Some browsers choose to implement them using prototype inheritance, but that is not required.

Comment: I never suggested IE<9 is wrong when compared against the standards.  I'm just asking for a list of all objects that fail to inherit in IE<9.

Comment: Also just my two sense about standards and what is "required" by browser vendors.  Basically standards are important, but certainly don't define how browsers will work.  There are plenty of other CSS and Html "standards" that have been around for a while, that IE 9 and down have failed to follow.  When looking at the web its most often about following the de facto standards.  A great example is how IE 9 has started to inherit from `Object.prototype` like most other browsers.  Its all about the de facto standards....well in IE<9's case definitely not standards :D

Comment: @Lime—there is a trend that browsers will gravitate toward standards (even IE has finally relented with version 9 and started supprting many more W3C standards). So you start from what is the specified behaviour and then make allowances for quirks. There is no reason to believe that **all** browser or user agent vendors will create DOM interfaces using an ECMAScript–compliant inheritance pattern. I also didn't suggest IE was wrong, only that it is an example of an implementation that chose to not implement prototype inheritance for it's DOM APIs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean `alert` is not inheriting from object and hasn't prototype:

```
 typeof alert; // "function"
 typeof alert.prototype; // "object"
```

Comment: In which browser? In many versions of IE (upto, but perhaps not including, 9), `typeof alert` shows *object*, `typeof alert.prototype` shows *undefined*. Besides, what you have posted doesn't show that *alert* inherits from *Object.prototype*, only that it returns certain values when used with the *typeof* operator.

Comment: I tested that in IE9, but maybe your version is different. Anyway, prototypical inheritance means that `alert` has a `object.prototype`, not is a `object.prototype`. In other words, imagine that your hands and mine are prototypical of Adam's hands. Now if Adam by the power of God get a pair of golden hands, you wake up in the morning seeing your hands are golden, just like mine.

Comment: I have no idea what your response means. I stated the versions of IE I was talking about, IE 9 isn't one of them. The OP asked about host objects inheriting from *Object.prototype*, in other words, host objects that have *Object.prototype* on their [[Prototype]] chain. Your post doesn't show that. If `typeof` shows *function*, it just indicates that it implements an internal [[Call]] property, it doesn't make it an instance of *Object* (ECMA-262 §11.4.3).